# Can't send an SMS between 2 emulators

Tags: android, listview, sms, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

My project is about communication between 2 phones, on which the app will be installed. 
The communication is an SMS communication, each SMS contains data and the receiving device must interpret it and sort in specified ListViews.
The project contains classes of: Send Data Form  and  class of 3 ListViews displaying the received data.

**My problem is** , that I'm not sure If my sms is sent(Because a dialog window does not appear after clicking the send button. Moreover, on the second emulator there is no indication whenever there is an incoming SMS message.

1. Send Data Form:

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.telephony.SmsManager;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class AddContactDeatils extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   Button sendToParallel, sendToParallel2;
   TextView nameT, idT, phoneT;
   EditText nameF, idF, phoneF;
   int recipient;




   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.add_contact_form);
   sendToParallel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendToParallel);
   sendToParallel.setOnClickListener(this);
   sendToParallel2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendToParallel2);
   sendToParallel2.setOnClickListener(this);
   nameT=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameTitle);
   idT=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.idTitle);
   phoneT=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.phoneTitle);
   nameF=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameField);
   idF=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.idField);
   phoneF=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneField);


       }
       protected void sendSms(String phoneNumber, String message) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
   sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
       }

       public void checkRecipient(EditText et)
       {
   try {
       recipient=Integer.parseInt(et.toString());
   } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO: handle exception
       Toast.makeText(this, "Only numbers are allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       et.setText("");
   }
       }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   int id=v.getId();

    String message = null;
    String name=nameF.toString();
    message+=name+";";
    String idTxt=idF.toString();
    message+=idTxt+";";
    String phone=phoneF.toString();
    message+=phone;

   switch(id)
   {
   case R.id.sendToParallel:
   {

       sendSms("5554", message) ; 


       break;
   }
   case R.id.sendToParallel2:
   {
       sendSms("5556", message) ; 
       break;
   }
   }

       }

           }
   ```
2. 3 ListViews Displaying recieved data

   ```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class DataLists extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
    ListView idList, namesList, phonesList;
    MyReciever mr;
    ArrayList<String>ids= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>names=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>phones=new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> idAdapter, namesAdapter, phonesAdapter;

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.details_lists);
   idList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.idList);
   namesList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.namesList);
   phonesList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.phonesList);
   idAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ids );
   idList.setAdapter(idAdapter);
   namesAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  names);
   namesList.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
   phonesAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, phones);
   phonesList.setAdapter(phonesAdapter);


       }
           public void addItemToIdList(String st)
           {
           ids.add(st);
           idAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }

           public void addItemToNamesList(String st)
           {
       names.add(st);
           namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }

           public void addItemToPhonesList(String st)
           {
           phones.add(st);
           phonesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }



      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      private class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
       SmsMessage[]msgs=null;
       if(bundle!=null)
       {
           Object[]pdus=(Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
           msgs=new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
           for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++)
           {
               int index=0, prev=0;
               String msgBody=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                index=msgBody.indexOf(';');
                prev=index;
                String name=msgBody.substring(0, index);
                addItemToNamesList(name);
                msgBody=msgBody.substring(index+1);
                index=msgBody.indexOf(';');
                String id=msgBody.substring(prev, index);
                addItemToIdList(id);
                msgBody=msgBody.substring(index+1);
                String phone=msgBody;
                addItemToPhonesList(phone);

           }
       }
      }

        }



         }
   ```

Comment: Try sending the sms between the two emulators manually before try it in code..

Comment: just do onething. Add a log message in the buttons. And check that it is firing the event or not in log cat window.

Comment: I tried , but the log tags do not appear in the log cat

Answer (score 0):

Add Pemissions for Send and Recive SMS

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
```

and Run Two Emulator for Send Sms.. eg 5554 to 5556